# Ui change stopped when playing media player running server url audio

Tags: android, url, audio, user-interface

I am running an application where i need to play an audio stored somewhere at a URL.

Before playing url i want to change the image of play button into pause.

I've hard time trying to do in the reference.

The UI is changed just after once it plays audio on URL and it takes 5-10 sec to play server URL. how can i change the image of the button before playing audio.

Can anybody please explain me why this is happening and what is the probable solution.

Please have a look over my code:-

```
((Button)v).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
                PlayPauseBtn.setId(1);

                Toast.makeText(RadioActivity.this, "Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                MediaController.mediaPlayStart(R.raw.acoustic_loop_bgm,
                        RadioActivity.this.getApplicationContext());


public static void mediaPlayStart(int resourcesId,final Context m_Context) {
    try {
        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        mp.setDataSource(m_Context, Uri.parse(Contants.audioURL));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.setLooping(true);

        try {
            mp.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("#####THE EXCEPTION IN THE MEDIA PLAYER PLAY==="+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here below is my logcat before playing sound.

```
06-21 17:15:17.661: W/KeyCharacterMap(1005): No keyboard for id 0
```

06-21 17:15:17.661: W/KeyCharacterMap(1005): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-21 17:15:21.910: I/System.out(1005): 00000000000000
06-21 17:15:21.910: I/System.out(1005): 2222222222
06-21 17:15:22.080: D/dalvikvm(1005): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3592 objects / 199296 bytes in 65ms
06-21 17:15:26.140: D/MediaPlayer(1005): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's maybe because you are using

```
mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

You better use the async method :

```
mediaPlayer.asyncPrepare();
```

This will not freeze your application and your icon will be changed immediatly.

EDIT :

```
mp.setDataSource(url); 
mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mp.prepareAsync();

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
    mp.start();
}
```

Comment: Ui chnaged successfully But now it's not working no audio playing.

Comment: Post you entire logcaton your first post please.

Comment: Please check my logcat before it plays sound.

Comment: Try to set the start of the mediaplyer like this : 
mp.setDataSource(url); 
mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mp.prepareAsync();

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
    mp.start();
}